# CSS element with position: fixed and width:100% is larger than its parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an element that has `position:fixed` and `width:100%`. The problem is that none of the parent elements have a fixed width. So my element is actually larger than any of its parent elements.

The implementation of my code is quite complex but I think I was able to simplify things. In the code below you will notice that the green box is larger than its parent elements.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        width: "100%",
        padding: "0px 15px",
        boxSizing: "border-box",
        height: "80px",
      }}
    >
      <div
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          border: "1px solid blue",
          height: "80px",
        }}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            width: "100%",
            border: "1px solid transparent",
            height: "80px",
          }}
        >
          <div style={{ width: "inherit", height: "25px" }}>
            <div style={{ width: "inherit", height: "25px" }}>
              <div
                style={{
                  width: "inherit",
                  position: "fixed",
                  height: "25px",
                  border: "1px solid green",
                }}
              ></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You don't have any elements with `position:fixed` and `width:100%`. I'm guessing you're talking about the inner element?

Comment: If you change all `width` properties to `inherit`, it works.  You can then set the width of the whole thing with a `maxWidth` property on the outermost div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block#identifying_the_containing_block

> If the position property is fixed, the containing block is established
> by the viewport (in the case of continuous media) or the page area (in
> the case of paged media).

even parent has width it will use the viewport as reference. Probably you can try `position: sticky` to achieve the same effect but using parent as reference point